# Problem with click event to bring a single user

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, for-loop, onclick

I'm new at coding in general, and I have this exercise where I need to bring a single additional user from an API (with name and image data) each time someone clicks on the button. I tried everything from hiding and and trying to show them one by one but i can't seem to find a way.

This is my latest attempt so far, I'm using vue js and j query

HTML markup:

````
<body>
    <div class="text-center mt-3" id="app">
      <h1>Lista de usuarios</h1>
      <div class="container col-5 md">
        <div id="box">
          <div class="users p-2" v-for="item in (users.data)">
            <img
              class="rounded-circle mt-3"
              v-bind:src=" item.avatar "
              alt="Imagen usuario"
            />
            <p>{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</p>
          </div>
          <div id="newusers">
                 <div
              class="users p-2"
              v-for="item in (users2.data)"
              style="display: none"
            >
              <img
                class="rounded-circle mt-3"
                v-bind:src=" item.avatar "
                alt="Imagen usuario"
              />
              <p>{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success mt-4" type="button" v-on:click="addUser">
        Agregar nuevo usuario
      </button>
    </div>```
````

Javascript code:

```
var userApp = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    users: {},
    users2: {},
  },
  methods: {
    addUser: function (event) {
      $("#newusers").append("<p>" + userApp.users2.data.first_name[0] + "</p>");
    },
  },
});
$.ajax({
  url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    userApp.users = data;
  },
});
$.ajax({
  url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    userApp.users2 = data;
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use jQuery with Vue. You can try with [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```js
var userApp = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
      page: 1,
      perPage: 6,
      total: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    hasMore() {
      return this.total > this.users.length
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addUser(event) {
      this.page++
      this.getUsers(this.page, 1)
    },
    getUsers(page, nr) {
      fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=" + page + "&per_page=" + nr)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.total = data.total
          this.users = [...this.users, ...data.data]
        });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getUsers(this.page, this.perPage)
    this.page = this.perPage
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="text-center mt-3" id="app">
    <h1>Lista de usuarios</h1>
    <div class="container col-5 md">
      <div id="box">
        <div class="users p-2" v-for="item in (users)" :key="item.id">
          <img
            class="rounded-circle mt-3"
            v-bind:src=" item.avatar "
            alt="Imagen usuario"
          />
          <p>{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success mt-4" type="button" v-on:click="addUser" v-if="hasMore">
      Agregar nuevo usuario
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: With that code after I click the button all users appear at once, I need that with each click a single user pops us, I'm already doing some research on fetch and thank you a lor for answering and for the info!!